# How to have the refresh token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, token, serverless

I need to use Google Play Android API, i follow a lot of instructions to be connected with the API but I block at one.([Authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization))
Exactly at the step 4 when they say:

Sending a Post with this code:

```
grant_type=authorization_code

code=<the code from the previous step>
client_id=<the client ID token created in the APIs Console>
client_secret=<the client secret corresponding to the client ID>
redirect_uri=<the URI registered with the client ID>`
```

I specify i use serverless and node, how can I do to have my refresh token in `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` please ?

Thank's a lot and sry for my english ^^.

---

Sry for this oversight, my serverless it’s just that

```
#serverless.yml
service: scrapper-app


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-3

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

and my js it’s just that too:

---

```
//index.js

const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//API

const { google } = require('googleapis');
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    IDCLient,
    Secret,
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
);

const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher';

const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes
)}


// GET
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Scrapper Rs!');
})



module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I really dont know how can i do http-post using node and serverless, i succeed with a database (with curl) but not post to an url.

Comment: Hello Jordan, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide a  more complete overview of your code so we can better determine what you might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't used Google Authentication. But I think you need to use access_type = offline

> **access_type     *Recommended***.  Indicates whether your application can
>   refresh access tokens when the user is not present at the browser.
>   Valid parameter values are online, which is the default value, and
>   offline.
>
> Set the value to offline if your application needs to refresh access
>   tokens when the user is not present at the browser. This is the method
>   of refreshing access tokens described later in this document. This
>   value instructs the Google authorization server to return a refresh
>   token and an access token the first time that your application
>   exchanges an authorization code for tokens.
>
> To set this value in PHP, call the setAccessType function:
>
> $client->setAccessType('offline');

Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Sry i forgot to share my code, access-type is in, thank's still i'ts my faut. :)